# Clearing an interval

Tags: javascript, intervals

I'm studying Javascript and I'm having difficulties and understanding why a piece of code (see below) I edited doesn't work. The purpose is pretty simple - I want to create a button that stops and runs time back again. I even printed text to be sure my code enters the 'if' and 'else' statements, but the clearInterval doesn't seem to work. Help much appreciated!

(*the original code belongs to w3schools, I have added the "loop function" just to see if it would work, and it doesn't ;( )

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="checkTime()">Stop time/Start time again</button>

<p id="test"></p>

<script>
var myCounter = 0;
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function checkTime() {
    myCounter += 1;
    if (myCounter == 1) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "ok";
    } else {
        var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
        myCounter = 0;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "clicked again";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `var myVar` introduces a new, local variable within `checkTime`, which shadows the global `myVar` variable. Remove the `var`.

Comment: Don't "re-declare" the `myVar` variable inside the loop in the function `checkTime()`. That makes it local the the function. Instead of `var myVar = ...` just do `myVar = ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just glanced at your code quickly, but I notice that you are redeclaring your `myVar` variable, which is the variable that is being cleared when you call `clearInterval` due to a funky feature in javascript called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Try the following...

```
<script>
var myCounter = 0;
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function checkTime() {
    myCounter += 1;
    if (myCounter == 1) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "ok";
    } else {
        myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
        myCounter = 0;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "clicked again";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: probably a duplicate answer now... :)

Comment: same to you. entering at the same time.

Comment: can't tell now but I was there a minute before ;) but yours explains hoisting better! +1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `var` from the second `var myVar = setInterval...`

The second one is scoped to your function and "overrides" the first one...

```
function checkTime() {
    myCounter += 1;
    if (myCounter == 1) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "ok";
    } else {
        myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
        myCounter = 0;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "clicked again";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!